# How to authenticate with an API key using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, apache, http, httpurlconnection

I'm having a hard time using the Java HttpURLConnection. Ive tried using HttpClient but that also failed.

All I want to do is this:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 1111111111" https://company.aha.io/api/v1/features/APP-1`

`1111111111` is the API key.

This is my code so far.

```
URL url = new URL("https://company.aha.io/api/v1/features/APP-1");
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//add request header for authentication
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
connection.connect();

System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

I keep getting a 404 code. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: 404 means the resource you're requesting does not exist. Does `curl` return the same error?

Comment: When I type the cURL command I get an `{"error":"Record not found."}`

Comment: Try adding `-v` to the `curl` command so you can see the headers. It most probably has a 404 status which means the URL is probably incorrect

Comment: When I use the flag `-v` I get a connection. Im also showing this code `HTTP/2 401` This is the API I'm using `https://www.aha.io/api`